# Search a contact with partial search string

Tags: android, sqlite, contacts, android-contacts

I want to search the contact list of the android user, by typing just 3-4 digits of a particular number. I have written the following method to do the same, but this is only working when I write complete 10 digit of the number and not less than that. It means it is only working with the exact match.
e.g I want to the number starting 98965... and so on.. but i only gives me a match when I type complete 9896511112

```
 public static void getContactDetails(Context context, String number, int type) {
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID,
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY,
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI,
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER};
        Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number.trim() + "%"));

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);

        while (Common.nonNull(cursor) && cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String lookUpKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY));
            String mobileNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER));
            Log.e("I am found", "Found " + number);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Please help me to find my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh finally. One thing that saved my day:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(partial));
```

Use **"ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI"** instead of **ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI**, and it will work for you.

Here is my complete example below:

```
public static void getContactDetails(Context context, String number, int type) {
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number.trim()));

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);

    while (Common.nonNull(cursor) && cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String lookUpKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY));
        String mobileNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));

        if (mobileNumber.length() > 10) {
            mobileNumber = mobileNumber.substring(mobileNumber.length() - 10);
            if (mobileNumber.startsWith(number)) {
                Log.e("I am found", "I am found " + mobileNumber + displayName);
            }
        }

    }

    cursor.close();
}
```